# MUI: How to update the DataGrid state programmatically?

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui, state

I am using the MUI `DataGrid` for displaying and filtering certain tabular data.

The `DataGrid` Toolbar contains buttons for filtering, sorting etc. I want to add a custom button that displays an option for certain predefined configurations. For example, assume that a `DataGrid` has 8 columns from ColA to ColH. If someone selects a presetA from the menu, the `DataGrid` only displays columns from A to C. Similarly, if someone selects a presetB from the menu, the `DataGrid` displays columns B and F. These columns are also reflected on clicking the Columns button Panel.
How can I implement this functionality?

I was able to add a custom button in the toolbar. But, unable to find a way to programmatically update the column visibility based on the preset selected.

I tried to access the `DataGrid` state using the following example from the documentation:

```
function CustomRowCounter() {
  const { rows } = useGridSlotComponentProps();

  return <div>Row count: {rows.length} </div>;
}
```

However, it throws an error:

> Error: Material-UI X: Could not find the data grid context. It looks
> like you rendered your component outside of a DataGrid or DataGridPro
> parent component. This can also happen if you are bundling multiple
> versions of the data grid.

I am using `DataGridPro` as follows:

```
import { DataGridPro, 
GridToolbar, 
GridToolbarColumnsButton, 
GridToolbarContainer, 
GridToolbarDensitySelector, 
GridToolbarExport, 
GridToolbarFilterButton, 
useGridApiRef,
useGridSlotComponentProps } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';
```

Following are the dependencies:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^4.0.1",
```

Comment: Can you show me how you use `DataGridPro` component?

Comment: I am using unlicensed product since I am just experimenting it. But we will be buying the XGrid license.
import {DataGridPro} from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro"; 
And while rendering write <DataGridPro .../>

Answer (score 3):

Implemented a demo using the Grid API.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-jepsen-ekgv2?file=/src/App.tsx

This is also taken up as a feature to be implemented to control the column visibility.
If you want to read more about this, refer https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/1412

Comment: using "useGridApiRef" instead of "useRef" part was the key for me to tackle a warning while using the "gridVisibleSortedRowIdsSelector" from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro" library

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GridApi.setColumnVisibility()`](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/grid-api/#:%7E:text=.-,setColumnVisibility,-(field%3A%20string%2C%20isVisible) to modify the column visibility state:

```
const setVisible = (columns) => () => {
  apiRef.current
    .getAllColumns()
    .map((c) => c.field)
    .forEach((c) => {
      const isVisible = columns.includes(c);
      apiRef.current.setColumnVisibility(c, isVisible);
    });

  handleClose();
};
```

```
<Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClick} sx={{ mb: 1 }}>
  Preset
</Button>
<Menu anchorEl={anchorEl} open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
  <MenuItem onClick={setVisible(["default"])}>Col1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem onClick={setVisible(["name", "stars"])}>
    Col2 & 3
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

---

About the error, you put your `CustomRowCounter` outside of `DataGridPro`. Because you're using `useGridSlotComponentProps` inside which needs access to the grid context data. This data is provided by [`GridContextProvider`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/blob/c1f420240cf9bd984557326a841d1b68febc54de/packages/grid/x-grid/src/DataGridPro.tsx#L40) - the root component of `DataGrid`/`DataGridPro`. To fix it you need to change from something like:

```
<DataGridPro {...} />
<CustomRowCounter />
```

To:

```
<DataGridPro
  components={{
    Footer: () => <CustomRowCounter />
  }}
/>
```

See the [slots section](https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid-pro/#slots) to know more about which components can be overridden inside `DataGridPro`.

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I actually wanted a preset button within the GridToolbar, exactly like the other GridToolbar buttons. I have been able to implement this using the GridAPI yesterday, posting the link to the sandbox in an answer below.

Comment: Also, I was trying to put the custom button component as you have shown and still got the error. Anyway, I have ditched useGridSlotComponentProps().